# Rotate a centered div about its central axis, using keyframes, without shifting its position

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to rotate a square div about its central axis.

Here is the div:

```
<div id='my_square' class='square'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
    border: 2px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    background: #227093;
    animation: rotate_x_180 2s;
}

.center {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes rotate_x_180{
    0% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

I am centering the div using javascript (since the positioning needs to be programmatic):

```
document.getElementById("my_square").classList.add("center")
```

This is the result:

[image]

Notice the shifting that occurs in position.

Is there a way to maintain the position so that the rotation only occurs about the central axis, with no shifting in position?

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0ekcsgo/1/)

As per @Fabrizio's comment, it does indeed appear that the animation if overriding the negative translation that was applied by JS. I tried to reset this at the end of the animation:

```
@keyframes rotate_x_180 {
    0% {transform: rotate(180deg)}
    100% {transform: rotate(0deg) transform: translate(-50%, -50%)}
}
```

...but the div does not maintain the center position.

Comment: You should provide the minimal code to reproduce the issue, anyway it seems that you applied a negative translation (like `translate(-50%, -50%)` and when the animation starts you lose the translation because you override the value of `transform`.

Comment: That cannot be literally all the code needed to reproduce the example because nowhere does it set the element to have that animation. Please provide a runnable snippet. Meanwhile, @FabrizioCalderan deduction that you are overriding an initial transform seems like the most likely answer.

Comment: @AHaworth all the code has been added, along with the link to the Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that the transforms in the keyframes are overriding the transform which translates the element back to the center.

You can have several settings in the tranform's value, but there can be only one tranform - any subsequent one will completely remove the first one.

Also note that it is important what order the transform settings are done in. In this snippet the square is positioned first with the translate and then rotated about its central point.

```js
document.getElementById("my_square").classList.add("center");
```

```css
.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  background: #227093;
  animation: rotate_x_180 2s;
}

.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes rotate_x_180 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='my_square' class='square'></div>
```

Comment: hmm so you always have to compensate for a previous translation that was made. That's really awkward.

Comment: Yes, though there are moves to make some, like scale, independent. In this specific case maybe centering a different way, eg flex, would obviate the need, but in the general case you have to accumulate transforms, and get the order right too.

Comment: makes sense, thank you. I decided to center the div by setting the top, bottom, left, and right to ‘0’ (since it’s positioned absolutely) and then setting the margin to ‘0 auto’.